# Get correct path from file picker

Tags: android, uri, pdfrenderer

I need to get a PDF file into my app. I already looked at similar questions and none of them work. The PdfReader keeps throwing an exception that says: File not found. So i figured the directory is wrong. Here is my code:

```
cardViewPlan.setOnClickListener(v -> {

        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        intent.setType("application/pdf");
        startActivityForResult(intent, FILE_PICK_RESULT_CODE);
    });

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    switch (requestCode) {
        case 1: {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                Uri uri = data.getData();

                String path = uri.getPath();
                File file = new File(path);

                txtFileName.setText(path);

                try {
                    PdfRenderer pdfRenderer = new PdfRenderer(ParcelFileDescriptor.open(file, ParcelFileDescriptor.MODE_READ_ONLY));

                    Bitmap bitmap;
                    final int pageCount = pdfRenderer.getPageCount();
                    for (int i = 0; i < pageCount ; i++) {
                        PdfRenderer.Page page = pdfRenderer.openPage(i);

                        int width = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().densityDpi / 72 * page.getWidth();
                        int height = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().densityDpi / 72 * page.getHeight();
                        bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

                        page.render(bitmap, null, null, PdfRenderer.Page.RENDER_MODE_FOR_DISPLAY);

                        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 30, baos);
                        byte[] bytes = baos.toByteArray();
                        String filename = "PDF_IMG_" + UUID.randomUUID().toString() + ".jpg";                           
                    }

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }
        break;

    }
}
```

Comment: read `ContentResolver` documentation on how to get `ParcelFileDescriptor` for a given `Uri`

Comment: IOW, a `Uri` is not a file.

Comment: @CommonsWare, read the code, then comment. Please :)

Comment: I did. `Uri uri = data.getData(); String path = uri.getPath(); File file = new File(path);` is treating the `Uri` as a file.

Comment: I tried everything and it still gives me the No such file or directory. What could be going wrong on retrieving the filepath?

Comment: have you read `ContentResolver` official documentation? if so, whats unclear in getting `ParcelFileDescriptor`?

Comment: @pskink it seems that the problem is at the path I'm sending to create the file. How do I retrieve the path from Intents Uri?

Comment: the problem is in **ParcelFileDescriptor** - have you read `ContentResolver` official documentation ? if so, whats unclear?

Comment: @pskink, I read it and seriously can't think of anything. Can you tell me what it is?

Comment: and you did not find any `ParcelFileDescriptor` related method?

Comment: I don't really know how or which to use?